# Doing TIN Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, interpolation, algorithm, tin

I want to do TIN Interpolation on a layer but when I fill all the fields with the right data (vector layer, interpolation attribute, extent etc) the algorithm does not run and shows me this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TinInterpolation.py",
  line 188, in processAlgorithm writer.writeFile(feedback)
  Exception: unknown Execution failed after 0.08 seconds
```

My QGIS version is 3.14 and the layer I want to do the interpolation is a shapefile with contours, exported from Surfer as .shp file

Does anybody have an idea about it?
[image: Interpolation parameters]

[image: Interpolation log]

[image: QGIS project]

Comment: Please send a picture of the TIN interpolation dialog with your settings.

Comment: What if you re-project your data to a plain (e.g. UTM or Mercator)?

Comment: I see you get a write error, so it might be because you have spaces in your output path. Try this on your local storage, not cloud, a path without spaces and greek letters, see if the error persists. Also, in data type you have selected points, while your data is line type.